# issues with injected content sizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a "live search" feature, this works fine functionally, however, on responsive testing, it breaks almost as soon as you get to tablet/mobile size.

I am using bootstrap for layout and the injected content from the live search is basically just a template that is injected.

Here is my HTML, SCSS and JS as it stands:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".brand-page-search-box").on("input", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var containerTemplate,
      itemTemplate,
      root = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

    containerTemplate = `<div class="row search-result-item-container"></div>`;

    $.ajax({
      url: root + '/posts/1',
      method: 'GET'
    }).then(function(data) {
      $(".search-results").html(containerTemplate);


      let returnedJSONToObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)),
        userID = returnedJSONToObj.userId,
        id = returnedJSONToObj.id,
        title = returnedJSONToObj.title,
        body = returnedJSONToObj.body;

      itemTemplate = `<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                                <div class="flip-container">
                                    <div class="card card-inverse">
                                        <div class="front">
                                            <div class="card-block">
                                                <h3 class="card-title">${title}</h3>
                                                <p class="card-text">${body}</p>
                                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="back">
                                            <div class="card-block">
                                                <h3 class="card-title">${title}</h3>
                                                <p class="card-text">${body}</p>
                                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                                <div class="flip-container">
                                    <div class="card card-inverse">
                                        <div class="front">
                                            <div class="card-block">
                                                <h3 class="card-title">${title}</h3>
                                                <p class="card-text">${body}</p>
                                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="back">
                                            <div class="card-block">
                                                <h3 class="card-title">${title}</h3>
                                                <p class="card-text">${body}</p>
                                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>`;

      $(".search-result-item-container").append(itemTemplate);
    });

    return false;
  });

});
```

```css
.flip-container {
  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
  perspective: 1000;
  .card {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    &: hover {
      transform: rotateY(180deg);
      -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }
    .front,
    .back {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      backface-visibility: hidden;
      -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    }
    .front {
      z-index: 2;
      .card-block {
        background: url("http://lorempixel.com/1920/1080/");
      }
    }
    .back {
      -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
      transform: rotateY(180deg);
      .card-block {
        background: url("http://lorempixel.com/900/500/");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid brand-search-bar">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="container">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <form action="#" id="form">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control brand-page-search-box" placeholder="Search">
                  <span class="input-group-btn">
                                      <button type="submit" class="btn">
    <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
                                    </span>
                </div>
              </form>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container brand-img-container search-results"></div>
```

Now, the cards inject into the post fine, but look at the following screens to see how the sizing goes:

Desktop:
[image]

Laptop/Tablet:

[image]

Mobile:

[image]

As you can see, on mobile, it totally breaks for some reason and the cards "fold" into one another, but if bootstrap is meant to be handling the layout, why is this happening?

The inspector isnt being much help, nor are some of the articles I have been reading on here and elsewhere, unusually, anyone got any ideas on how to fix this?

I am using bootstrap 4 and jquery 2 if that helps.

If you have any questions, comments or requests, please do ask in the comments below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix the *flip effect css*. Nothing to do with twitter bootstrap.
Your `.flip-container` is not getting height, so in xs when many containers stack you see the probleme.

You could set a fixed height for your `.flip-container` but since you want dynamic height here is a solution

Add `.front{ position:relative}` and `.back{top: 0}`

```
.flip-container {
  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
  perspective: 1000;
  .card {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    &:hover {
      transform: rotateY(180deg);
      -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }
    .front,
    .back {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      backface-visibility: hidden;
      -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    }
    .front {
      z-index: 2;
      position:relative; <---
      .card-block {
        background: url("http://lorempixel.com/1920/1080/");
      }
    }
    .back {
      -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
      transform: rotateY(180deg);
      top:0; <---
      .card-block {
        background: url("http://lorempixel.com/900/500/");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Also I suggest you add a .row in between your .search-results and the .col-xx-xx from templates.